# Фиксирование блока при прокрутке

Tags: jquery, html, css

Хочу сделать, чтобы при прокрутке, например на `100px` сверху, блок `#nav` фиксировался, а точнее добавлялся класс `.fixed`. Ну и наоборот, если скролл меньше `100px` сверху, до убираем класс.

Я вроде нашел решение, но оно не совсем то. Помогите плиз )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var block_btn = $(".b_fix");
    var offset = block_btn.offset();
    if(offset.top <= 30){
        $("#nav").removeClass('nav_fixed');
    }
    else {
        $("#nav").addClass('nav_fixed');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.b_fix{
    height: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="b_fix"></div>
```

Обязательно добавить пустой блок на страницу.

Эх, люблю отвечать на свои же вопросы :)

Comment: А что таоке block_btn?

Comment: аахах, смысл пустого блока, можно просто вверху сделать отступ побольше меньше мороки

Comment: сам задал сам и ответил, норм чё карму  се подимает

Comment: @LinuX_UseR на карму я не мастурб... ну вы поняли. Нашел решение. Раз уж никто не ответил, то почему бы не помочь другим и не поделиться им, нежели закрывать или удалять вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Вот как-то так:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
    var the_top = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    if (the_top > 100) {
        jQuery('#nav').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Comment: а как быть чтобы сохранить fixed блок при обновлении страницы? потому что в коде выше блок становится фиксированным, только когда произошло событие скролла